# How to return a dict with lists as values but it only returns me the keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've got a dict1 that looks like the following:

```
{"A":["a","b","c"],"B":["b","d","e"],"C":["a","e"]}
```

My goal is to write a function that gets listA as input.
listA could be ["a","b","c","e"] for example.
I now want to return a dict2 with all elements from dict1 which have all their elements included in listA.

Output should look like this:

```
{'A':["a","b","c"],"C":["a","e"]}
```

My code looks like this:

```
def func(listA: list) -> dict:
    return set(x for x in dict1 if all(x in listA for x in dict1[x]))
```

My output only returns the keys, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict1 = {"A":["a","b","c"],"B":["b","d","e"],"C":["a","e"]}
listA =  ["a","b","c","e"]
dict2 = {key: l for key, l in dict1.items() if all(val in listA for val in l)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original dictionary is fixed, and only `listA` is taken as an input to the function, then you should change the dictionary to contain sets instead of lists. Sets are faster to test membership of, so they are faster to test *subsets* of; this can be done using the overloaded `<=` operator, which makes the code cleaner, too.

```py
dict_of_lists = {
    "A": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "B": ["b", "d", "e"],
    "C": ["a", "e"]
}
dict_of_sets = { k: set(v) for k, v in dict_of_lists.items() }

def func(listA):
    setA = set(listA)
    return { k: v for k, v in dict_of_lists.items() if dict_of_sets[k] <= setA }
```

Example:

```py
>>> func(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'])
{'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'C': ['a', 'e']}
```

Consider also whether it would make sense for your inputs and outputs to use sets instead of lists. If you don't really need to maintain the ordering or allow duplicates, then you could just use `dict_of_sets` in the first place, and `func` wouldn't need to convert the list to a set either:

```py
dict_of_sets = {
    "A": {"a", "b", "c"},
    "B": {"b", "d", "e"},
    "C": {"a", "e"}
}

def func(setA):
    return { k: v for k, v in dict_of_sets.items() if v <= setA }
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
dict1[x]
```

use`

```
dict1.values[x]
```